# Codeblocks is not printing anything in Linux Mint

Tags: c, linux, gcc, codeblocks, linux-mint

I just installed Codeblocks in Linux Mint from Software Manager (I'm new to Linux). I wrote a hello world program which is not printing anything and also not showing any error.

At first it was showing, "fatal error: stdio.h: no such file or dirrectory".
I Googled and performed some commands like,
sudo apt-get install g++, and others.
There's no more any error, but it's not showing any output.

Then I wrote the sane code in a file and then tried to run it from terminal, it worked fine! The only problem happens with the Codeblocks.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I think the problem is with the GCC configuration. But I don't know how to configure or add path for GCC in Linux Mint (as this is my first day in Linux)

Comment: CB has a 'Build log' window. When you try to build the code, are there any messages in that window?

Comment: Probably not your GCC configuration anymore. See above comment.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: 
When I build, it says:
-------------- Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown)---------------

gcc   -c /home/fahim/Desktop/hello.c -o /home/fahim/Desktop/hello.o
g++  -o /home/fahim/Desktop/hello /home/fahim/Desktop/hello.o   
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Comment: @SMFahim Maybe the output window closes immediately? Try adding `getchar()` before `return`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: still the same. Process terminated with status -1

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this kind of error when you are trying to run the program?

```
Process terminated with status -1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

[image: img_error]

If yes, then go to Settings -> Environment... -> General Settings -> Select `gnome-terminal -t $TITLE -x`  from the `Terminal to launch console programs:` dropdown menu -> Press the OK button

[image: img_solutions]

**Additional:** Choosing terminal depends on your OS environment. Suppose if you are using `Xfce` desktop then you can choose `xfce4-terminal -T $TITLE -x`. For `gnome` desktop, select `gnome-terminal -t $TITLE -x`.

If you want you can install an additional terminal too. Such as `XTERM` terminal,  Run this command in the terminal `sudo apt-get install xterm`
& select `xterm -T $TITLE -e` from the `Terminal to launch console programs:` dropdown menu

Answer (score -1):

> sudo apt install --reinstall build-essential 
>   might work

Comment: No it's not working. Still the same. Building but not running